# Use intent to upload files to Google Drive

Tags: android-intent

I am getting the error: "Upload failed. Failed to schedule 1 file for upload". I am trying to create a simple file explorer. When user taps on a non-folder item on listView, a Google Drive upload dialog will appear but I got the error when i tap on SAVE button from Google Drive dialog. Below shows my coding. Please do tell me what or which parts I am doing wrong. Thank you.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Option o = adapter.getItem(position);
    if(o.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("folder")||o.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("parent directory")){
        currentDir = new File(o.getPath());
        fill(currentDir);
    }
    else
    {
        onFileClick(o);
    }
}

private void onFileClick(Option o)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "File Clicked: "+o.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String uri = o.getPath();
    Uri uploadUri = Uri.parse(uri);
    Toast.makeText(this, "This file is located at: "+uploadUri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (uri.contains(".txt")) {
        Intent uploadIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
                .setText("Share Document")
                .setType("application/txt")
                .setStream(uploadUri)
                .getIntent()
                .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs");
        startActivity(uploadIntent);
    }else{
        //TODO: what to do when it is other file format
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside onFileClick():

Change

```
String uri = o.getPath();
```

to

```
String uri = "file://" + o.getPath();
```

and there you go!!  :)